# Google BigQuery create simple count table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to user Google Bigquery to store number of searches for certain keyword in my site. I create table structure like this:

```
| date       | keyword | number_of_searches |
| 2017-03-29 | pizza   | 1                  |
```

I want to increment number_of_searches value if combination of date and keyword already exists.

Comment: BigQuery is not optimal for updating.  Insert rows for each search and then count them when you query the table.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you wanted a solution to store number of searches for certain keyword.

Using BigQuery technology you need to change some approach.

Let's discuss traditional steps:
- use a `SELECT` to find out if there is a row for today
- if not, then `INSERT` one with default
- when exists, use an `UPDATE` statement to increment counter

With BigQuery where the main change is that it's append only and it's not suitable to do UPDATE statements, you need to change how you analyse data and simplify the collection. Instead of doing 3 steps like above you would do one:
- insert a new row for each search

This way you will end up with multiple rows, and you can aggregate to find out the value and can run a query to find out how many searches you had for your queries, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
   myday as date,
   keyword,
   count(1) as number_of_search
FROM table
group by 1,2
```